# Radio button group Select & Change / onChange

Tags: xpages

It looks like the Select & Change  / onChange event is not being called for my radion button group.  In the SSJS sample below, the onChange event of radio button group should set the value of the edit box and also do a full update.  Neither seems to be occurring.

```
<xp:radioGroup id="radioGroup1">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="One"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Two"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Three"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("inputText1").setValue(getComponent("radioGroup1").getValue());}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:radioGroup>
On Select should set this:&#160;<xp:inputText id="inputText1"></xp:inputText>
<xp:br></xp:br>
Selected Value:&#160;<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" style="font-weight:bold"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return getComponent("radioGroup1").getValue();}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:button value="Update" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
<xp:br></xp:br>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OnChange event for a radio group doesn't work properly in IE. OnClick event works. So you need to write code based on the browser, as follows.

```
<xp:radioGroup id="radioGroup1">
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="One"></xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Two"></xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Three"></xp:selectItem>
<xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelRadioVal" rendered="#{javascript:!context.getUserAgent().isIE()}" />
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelRadioVal" rendered="#{javascript:context.getUserAgent().isIE()}" />
</xp:radioGroup>
<xp:panel id="panelRadioVal">
    <xp:inputText value="#{javascript:getComponent('radioGroup1').getSubmittedValue()}" />
</xp:panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your first getComponent in your eventhandler should be "inputText1" not "inputText".

Also, why perform a full update and not a partial refresh?  Just trying to understand the business case.

Comment: It was a typo.  Believe me the event is never being called.   The reason I am doing a full update is that it is just a demo as I mentioned.  I am not worried about efficiency.

Comment: Try setting the value to something hardcoded to verify that onChange fires. Then try using getSubmittedValue() for getting the value of the radio box.